# Residue of $\frac {z}{z^6+1}$ at $z=i$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Is there an easy way to find the residue of $$\frac {z}{z^6+1}$$

at $z=i$? the formula given by taylor theorem doesn't seem to help and evaluating $(z-i)\frac {z}{z^6+1}$ at $z=i$ seems to laborious. maybe I am wrong about this and it's not that hard to  to do this calculations, but if that's the case, I'm missing something.

The residue is $\frac{1}{6}$ by the way

Comment: How about some factoring? I see the sum of cubes in the denom.

Comment: It's really not that "laborious", you shouldn't be afraid of small computations like that. $z^6 + 1 = (z^3)^2 - i^2 = \dots$?

Comment: I know how to factor it, but then I have to compute $i-s$ for every singularity $s$ except $s=i$.

Answer (score 5):

The denominator $d(z) = z^6+1$ has a simple zero at $z = i$, so the residue is simply

$$\frac{i}{d'(i)} = \frac{i}{6 i^5} = \frac{1}{6i^4} = \frac{1}{6}.$$

Whenever we have a quotient

$$\frac{f(z)}{g(z)}$$

where $g$ has a simple zero in $z_0$, the residue of $\frac{f}{g}$ in $z_0$ is

$$\frac{f(z_0)}{g'(z_0)},$$

as can be seen from writing $g(z) = (z-z_0)\cdot h(z)$ with $h(z_0) = g'(z_0) \neq 0$.

Comment: thank you, exactly what I wanted

Answer (score 4):

Since the pole is first order we can multiply by $z-i$ and use L'Hospital to get the residue:
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{z\to i}z\frac{z-i}{z^6+1}
&=\lim_{z\to i}z\lim_{z\to i}\frac1{6z^5}\\
&=i\frac1{6i}\\
&=\frac16
\end{align}
$$

Comment: I deleted my answer because it uses the same idea as Daniel Fischer, but I think it relevant to point out that we are using L'Hospital.

Comment: @GregMartin: I hope you don't mind if I roll back your edit. I think it makes the answer more confusing. However, I see that you are trying to isolate L'Hospital, so I added that in :-)

Comment: I don't mind that you rolled it back (it's your answer!). For what it's worth, I do think that the extra step you removed made it more clear - in particular, more clear to someone to whom these ideas are new. (And pixels are cheap....)

Answer (score 0):

$$z^6+1=z^6-i^6=(z^3-i^3)(z^3-i)=(z-i)(z^2+iz-1)(z^3-i)$$

$$\lim_{z\to i}(z-i)\frac{z}{z^6+1}=\frac{i}{-3(-2i)}=\frac{1}{6}$$